# Need to add the date of a linked table to an Access report

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created an Access database that takes information from linked Excel tables to create queries, reports, etc.  The Excel tables are created by extracting data from another program via BIRT, saving the XML tables BIRT creates and then converting them to Excel.  We can't just import the files as XML because Access 2010 splits the information into several (unusable) tables.My users will be doing this frequently, once each week or more often, in order to keep the information in the reports "fresh".

How can I put the date the linked table was created into a report?  Can it even be done at all?

I have looked on the Web and through various other sites, but no one seems to address this question.  I have considered making a table where the user would be required to put in the date the tables were created and using that information in the reports, but I am afraid of user resentment, which is already pretty high at the thought of having to extract data via BIRT in the first place.  The only reason we are doing this at all is because BIRT reports are "ugly" and hard for upper management to read, which is a compelling business use case.

Ideas, please?

Comment: What drives the creation of the linked table?  Is that done with Excel VBA code?  Or is that an entirely manual operation?

Comment: It is entirely a manual process.  The user goes to the original software (IBM's WebSphere Service Registry and Repository), opens a BIRT report and exports it to what BIRT calls Excel (really an XML file).  The user then opens the XML file in Excel 2010 and saves it as an Excel 2010 file.  There are some field formatting changes that the user has to do - text to number - as well.

Comment: Is the XML file's date/time attribute a reasonable substitute for the linked table's creation date?  Or perhaps the same attribute for the Excel file itself?

Comment: The XML file's date/time attribute is the important thing.  It should be the same as the Excel table, since I expect the user will do the BIRT to Excel conversion on the same day.  However, what upper management will want to know is how "fresh" the information in the report is, which is the date of the XML file.

Comment: Then does VBA like this give you what you want?  `MsgBox FileDateTime("C:\SomeFolder\YourFile.XML")`

Comment: Would I put code like that in the VBA for the report? For a textbox?

Comment: Do note MS Access can also [import XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823157.aspx) directly and even into multiple tables depending on structure.

Comment: I agree with @Parfait, you can use importing to XML. you tube has few videos to demonstrate. IT is very easy to implement